# Why these two has different values?

Tags: java

```
Double milisecondsInYear = 365*24*3600*1000;
```

It's `1.7e9`

But if I used

```
Double milisecondsInYear = 365*24*3600*1000.;
```

I got correct answer `3.15E10`

Comment: Beside the correct answers posted. Your first line would not compile. On the left side you have an `Double` object type and on the right side you have a `int` primitve and they are not assign compatible. So next time post the real code you have used.

Comment: I typed this in phone. It auto corrected. Sorry.

Comment: sad that I could not add only a smiley for your answer. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Because `365`, `24`, `3600` and `1000` are all `int` literals, the calculation is done using `int`s. The multiplication overflows because the true value exceeds `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. By putting a dot at the end you turn that last literal into a `double` literal. This is not a very robust way to correct it because the multiplication of the first 3 numbers is still carried out using `int`s. The best way to deal with this is to make the first number a `long` or `double` literal.

```
365L*24*3600*1000
```

or

```
365.0*24*3600*1000
```

Answer (score 3):

Because of overflow. `365*24*3600*1000` does not fit in an int (which is a signed 32-bit value). If you write that as `365L*24*3600*1000` then the necessary promotions will happen in the proper order and the result will be a `long`, which can fit that number.

In the second line, you have an extra character, the dot at the end - this makes the number a floating-point number, thus you lose in precision but you can actually do the multiplications.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers in Java are `int`s, unless you specify otherwise.

When you add `.`, you'll have `double` calculations (since `1000.0` is `double`) instead of `int`, which fits (unlike `int`).

Answer (score 1):

The first is performing integer math, because all of the numbers are integers the result is an integer (which is then widened to a `double`). The range of an `int` isn't sufficient for the result. A `double` or a `long` is. So, you could also use

```
double millisecondsInYear = (365L * 24 * 3600 * 1000);
System.out.println(millisecondsInYear);
```

to widen to `long` first. The above also outputs "3.1536E10".

Answer (score 0):

The order or evaluation differes depending on the types you are using. That's why you get different answers.

Comment: Thanks all. This bug stucked me a while.

Comment: How does the order matter here?